# Mobile chrome browser doesn't display my div or results data

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I have the following piece of React code on my website that shows the search results div only if the search results exist. The backend limits search results to only 20 items at a time, and each item is a dictionary with only three key-value pairs.

This works perfectly on all desktop browsers and also Firefox on Android. But **on Android Chrome the search results never show**. I've tried changing the display to always block, letting the height and width be undefined, and tons of different formatting changes.

Is there something related to div height or data displayed for mobile Chrome? Has anyone encountered this?

```
<div
  style={{
    height: 150,
    width: "100%",
    overflowY: "scroll",
    display: this.props.hasSearchResults ? "" : "None"
  }}
>
  {/* switch to a div */}
  {/* <List> */}
  {this.props.search_results.map((result, idx) => (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        size="small"
        edge="end"
        onClick={event => {
          this.handleMenuAdd(event, result);
        }}
        style={{height: "100%"}}
      >
        <AddIcon
          style={{margin: "auto"}}
          fontSize="small"
        />
      </IconButton>
      <Typography
        style={{verticalAlign: "bottom"}}
        noWrap={true}
        // display="block"
        variant="caption"
      >
        {result.name}
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        variant="caption"
        style={{marginLeft: 10}}
        noWrap={true}
      >
        {result.item_type}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is more likely to be a css one. Try with position: fix. top left right bottom: 0. z-index: 1000000

Comment: I will try that an let you know. You mean all of those on the outer div right?

Comment: Unfortunately none of those (or all together) fixed the issue. It works correctly in Firefox but as soon as the loading spinner stops in Chrome it disappears.

Comment: Could you provide an online demo (jsfiddle/stackblitz/etc)? That way could be easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, I'll add that today

Comment: Did you try `display: this.props.hasSearchResults ? "block" : "none"` ? You can also inspect your mobile browser from your desktop to see what's going on. It could also be the parent element styling.

Comment: Yes, I did try it with "block" and got same results. Interesting I didn't realize debugging from desktop was a capability. I've found some articles and will try that. Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you type `100vw` instead of `100%`?

Comment: I found the problem unfortunately it was a silly capitlization error. However I realized it by linking mobile chrome to my desktop so that I was able to see no search results were being shown. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your attention and input. The problem was serverside. It simply wasn't lowercasing the search query. In Chrome the input was being automatically capitalized and in Firefox it wasn't. Feeling silly but will leave this here in case someone else needs to see it.